# Android, how to send Exception through IPC

Tags: android, ipc

I have two applications, which are binding and then first app calls some function from second app. In case some thing happen wrong in second app it throws exception.
I would like to send this Exception, which was thrown in second application to first app. Which mechanism is the most suitable for this?

Answer (score 0):

The Throwable.class is already Serializable so you can use the Messenger to send this Exception by adding it to the Messenger Bundle, assuming that you already know how to interact between processes using the Messenger pattern. Also please have in mind that if you use a custom Exception class you need to set the ClassLoader into the Bundle when you deserialize in the second process.